# How do I get an appropriate typeclass instance at runtime?

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless

**Part I**

Suppose I have a type class `trait Show[T] { def print(t: T): String }` with instances for `String` and `Int`. Suppose I have a value whose specific type is known only at runtime:

```
val x: Any = ...
```

How do I get the appropriate typeclass instance (at runtime, since we don't know the type statically) and do something with it.

Note that it's inadequate to define a method that literally just gives us the typeclass instance:

```
def instance(x: Any): Show[_]
```

Since `Show.print` requires statically known argument type `T` we still can't do anything with the result of `instance`. So really, we need to be able to dynamically dispatch to an already-defined function that *uses* the instance, such as the following:

```
def display[T](t: T)(implicit show: Show[T]) = "show: " + show.print(t) + "\n"
```

So assuming `display` is defined, how do we invoke `display`, passing along an appropriate `Show` instance. I.e. something that invokes `display(x)` properly.

Miles Sabin accomplishes this here using runtime compilation (Scala eval), as an example of "staging", but with only spare documentation as to what's going on:

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/staging.scala

Can Miles's approach be put into a library? Also, what are the limitations of this approach e.g. with respect to generic types like `Seq[T]`?

**Part II**

Now suppose `T` is bounded by a sealed type (such that it's possible to enumerate all the sub-types):

```
trait Show[T <: Foo]
sealed trait Foo
case class Alpha(..) extends Foo
case class Beta(..) extends Foo
```

In this case, can we do it with a macro instead of runtime compilation? And can this functionality be provided in some library?

I mostly care about Scala 2.12, but it's worth mentioning if a solution works in 2.11 or 2.10.

Comment: For part II I think it makes more sense to just define one function that pattern matches over all the leafs of the class hierarchy than to have a typeclass.

Comment: I think that would be OK, and that's more or less what I have in my code right now. But I happen to have this pattern in my code more than once, so the pattern match is starting to feel like boilerplate to me. Putting the print() implementations in separate objects also seems like better modularity in my actual situation. Also if this can be generalized, it seems like a powerful tool.

Comment: FWIW my actual situation is: I have a CLI program with subcommands. Each subcommand has its own case class. I'm using a typeclass for the execution of each command: https://github.com/tksfz/doto2/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/tksfz/doto/main/Main.scala

Comment: @tksfz has there been any progress towards a generic, non pattern matching solution?

Comment: no i haven't heard of any solutions